# Object comparisons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand the weird behaviour of JavaScript identity and equality operator as given below.

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
a === b; //false
a == b;  //false

var c = '';
var d = '';
c === d; //true
c == d;  //true
```

All four variables `a` ,`b` ,`c` and `d` are objects. But when comparing them, first case yields false whereas second one true.

I studied comparison from the following source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d53a7bd4(v=vs.94).aspx

According to the above article, except number and boolean everything is compared by reference instead of value. So how the first case returns false and second one true.

Comment: `So how the first case returns true and second one false.` other way around, first is false, second is true

Comment: Strings are primitives. Welcome to the beautiful world of JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is String a Primitive type or Object in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript)

Comment: try `var c = new String(''), d = new String('');` then see how you go

Comment: The article you linked to in the question says explicitly that strings are compared by value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` and `d` in your example are strings, [which are primitive types in JavaScript and compared by value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type).

For this reason, `c == d` returns `true`.

The article is talking about [string objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) created usng the `new String('foo')` constructor, which actually creates objects. In this case, the references are compared, returning `false`.

```js
console.log(new String('foo') == new String('foo')) // false
console.log('foo' == 'foo')                         // true
```

Answer (score 0):

A (primitive) string is a value type (like Number). As such `===` compares its value (equality).

Objects are reference types, and for them `===` compares identity.

Strings are a bit crazy, as there are both primitive strings and String objects (created with `new String("foo")`).

---

`==` works the same way as `===` except that it does type conversions to "make things equal if possible". For reference types this is the same as `===`, except that it also equates primitive strings and String objects.

```
 "abc" == new String("abc");
 "abc" !== new String("abc");
```