# Unable to add a property to an object using either the dot notation or the indexer notation?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a property named `params` to a property named `url` of a class named `Page`. The property `params` must be assigned the return value of an anonymous function.

The function runs just fine.

However, *after* assigning the return value of the function, when I check to see if the property `params` has been assigned to, I see no such property in the watches window or in the console. When I try to read back the property `params` from the `url` property, I get `undefined`.

Why is that? This happens whether I use the dot notation or the indexer notation to write / assign a value to the property. Below is my code:

```
var app = 
{
    ...
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = new Page(app);
    page.display();
});

var Page = function(app) {

    this.url = window.location.href;
    this.app = app;

    this.url.params = (function() {

        var p = { };

        if (this.indexOf('?') < 0) return p;

        var query = this.split('?')[1];

        var pairs = query.split('&');

        if (pairs === undefined || pairs.length == 0) return p;

        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].trim();

            if (pair.length == 0) continue;

            if (pair.indexOf('=') < 0) {
                p[pair[0]] = '';
            }
            else {
                var prop = pair.split('=');

                p[prop[0]] = prop[1];
            }
        }

    }.bind(this.url))();

    this.display = function() {

        debugger;

        // over here, when I watch 'url', it does
        // not have a 'params' property
    };
};
```

Comment: You return nothing from your function, so there's undefined assigned to your object

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. :-) Would you like to put that down as an answer?

Comment: Okay, I fixed that but it still remains `undefined`. Is it because `url` is a `String` and we can't add properties dynamically to a `String`? Can we?

Comment: No, a string doesn't have properties.

Comment: You mean I can't add custom properties to an object of type `String`?

Comment: A string is not an object in javascript

Comment: @baao > *A string is not an object in javascript* Oh, oh! I thought *everything* was an object in JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What you have is a string literal, not an object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript

Comment: Ah! Thank you. So, you're saying I can't add custom properties to a string literal but can to a string object. I see.

Comment: Just create a plain object and at the url and the param as properties

Comment: @baao Yes, I understand how to fix the problem. Just curious to learn since we touched a nice topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning properties to primitive string values does not cause an error. Instead it internally promotes the string type to a String object, performs the assignment and then discards the String object.

The reason for doing this is to enable the use of String.prototype getters and methods on primitive string values. (Similar considerations apply to using Number.prototype methods on primitive number type values)

In your case

```
this.url = window.location.href;
```

sets `this.url` to a primitive string value. Then when you set `url.params` to a function it is internally and effectively treated as

```
new String(this.url).params = function () ....
```

for the purposes of the assignment, but the String object created gets discarded after the statement has been executed. The primitive value in `this.url` does not gain properties - it is not an object data type and doesn't have properties.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add the return statement of the function. Fix that and your code will work pretty well :D

Comment: I fixed that but it still reports `undefined`. Are we allowed to add custom properties on an object of type `String`?

Answer (score 0):

<del>First, the bind syntax/call is wrong. You actually don't need to use `bind` function to do something like this. Is there a specific reason you are using `bind`?</del> I made this work by just passing the `window.location.href` to the `url.params` assignment function; also I've changed the `url` to initialize as an empty object `this.url = {};`.

My full working code:

```
var app = 
{
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = new Page(app);
    page.display();
});

var Page = function(app) {

    //this.url = window.location.href;
    this.url = {};
    this.app = app;

    this.url.params = (function(url) {

        var p = { };

        if (url.indexOf('?') < 0) return p;

        var query = url.split('?')[1];

        var pairs = query.split('&');

        if (pairs === undefined || pairs.length == 0) return p;

        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].trim();

            if (pair.length == 0) continue;

            if (pair.indexOf('=') < 0) {
                p[pair[0]] = '';
            }
            else {
                var prop = pair.split('=');

                p[prop[0]] = prop[1];
            }
        }

        return p;

    })(window.location.href); //.bind(window.location.href /*this.url*/)();

    this.display = function() {

        debugger;

        console.log('display', this.url);

        // This url (http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/js-bind.html?some=1&url=2&vars=3)
        // Outputs in the console:
        // Object
        //  params: Object
        //    some: "1"
        //    url: "2"
        //    vars: "3"

    };
};
```

You can check the debugger and the console after you resume the debugger breakpoint (example with `?some=1&url=2&vars=3` url query string):

```
Object
 params: Object
   some: "1"
   url: "2"
   vars: "3"
```

And you can check my working example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/js-bind.html?some=1&url=2&vars=3

**EDIT**

It appears that your code works quite well. You just have to initialize `this.url` to be an object like `this.url = {};` and then just return the `p` array inside the binded function like this:

```
var Page = function(app) {

    //this.url = window.location.href;
    this.url = {};
    this.href = window.location.href;
    this.app = app;

    this.url.params = (function(url) {

        var p = { };

        if (this.indexOf('?') < 0) return p;

        var query = this.split('?')[1];

        var pairs = query.split('&');

        if (pairs === undefined || pairs.length == 0) return p;

        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].trim();

            if (pair.length == 0) continue;

            if (pair.indexOf('=') < 0) {
                p[pair[0]] = '';
            }
            else {
                var prop = pair.split('=');

                p[prop[0]] = prop[1];
            }
        }

        return p;

    }.bind(this.href))();

    this.display = function() {
        debugger;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is the `bind` call wrong in my case? It works just fine in the code snippet I posted in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I am wrong. It absolutely works if you convert the `url` to an object and then use another property to pass the url. You also have to return the `p` array from the `params` function. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as pointed out by @baao in the comments to the question is -- you may not add custom properties to a string literal but you can, to a `String` object. There is a difference between the two.

The code snippet below proves this.

```js
var foo = "foo";
var bar = new String("bar");

foo.foo = "foo";
bar.bar = "bar";

alert(foo.foo);
alert(bar.bar);
```

The fix, which was obvious, was to change the `url` to being an object. This has also been demonstrated by @Christos Lytras and suggested by @baao in the comments to the original question.

```
var app = 
{
    ...
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = new Page(app);
    page.display();
});

var Page = function(app) {

    this.url = { url : window.location.href };
    this.app = app;

    this.url.params = (function() {

        var p = { };

        if (this.indexOf('?') < 0) return p;

        var query = this.split('?')[1];

        var pairs = query.split('&');

        if (pairs === undefined || pairs.length == 0) return p;

        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].trim();

            if (pair.length == 0) continue;

            if (pair.indexOf('=') < 0) {
                p[pair[0]] = '';
            }
            else {
                var prop = pair.split('=');

                p[prop[0]] = prop[1];
            }
        }

        return p;

    }.bind(this.url.url))();

    this.url.getErrorMessage = function() {
        return this.params['error'];
    };

    this.url.getAccesToken = function() {
        return this.params['access_token'];
    };

    this.url.search = function(pattern) {
        return this.url.search(pattern);
    }

    this.display = function() {

        ...
    };
};
```