# why " ".abcd is returning undefined value instead of throwing undefined error in Javascript (But Typescript throwing a warning)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please check this below 3 snippets and let me know how it works

### Snippet 1

I can see this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: aaa is not defined",` while running the below snippet. I know because we didn't define `aaa` variable.

```js
var a=aaa;
```

### Snippet 2

And also I am  getting `\"string\".abcd is not a function"` error for this below snippet.

```js
var a="string".abcd();
```

### Snippet 3

> But why this below snippet does not throw an error like, `Uncaught ReferenceError: abcd is not defined",` ? and  why `"string".abcd` returning undefined?

```js
var a=" ".abcd;
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Because that is exactly how the language works by design.

Comment: Accessing undefined property returns `undefined`.

Comment: Look to coercion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript

Comment: @AluanHaddad But typescript does not allow it.

Comment: @dfsq But why undefined method  throw the error?

Comment: TypeScript provides design time facilities. It doesn't change JavaScript but it will give you a warning for this. That's what it is there for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`athing.something` means "Get the property called `something` from `athing`".

If a property doesn't exist, then it has the value `undefined`.

Your newly created string doesn't have an `abdc` property.

---

You can't compare it to Snippet 1 because you are dealing with a property, not a variable.

You can compare it to Snippet 2, which complains that it is not a function - `undefined` is, indeed, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Because `" "` is a string, and javascript provides some default properties like `" ".length`. since there is no default `.abcd` it just says it is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is equivalent to:

```
var a = " ";
a.abcd;
```

It basically checks the abcd property in the prototype of the String constructor. Snippet gives an error because you are calling:

```
undefined()
```