# Typescript type matching object whose valueOf eventually returns a string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm overengineering a type that matches a `string` or an object whose `valueOf()` when evaluated recursively, eventually returns a `string`.

```ts
type Stringable = string | StringableObject;
interface StringableObject {
    valueOf(): Stringable;
}

let x: Stringable;

// should work:
x = 'foo';

x = {
    valueOf() { return 'foo'; }
};

x = {
    valueOf() {
        return {
            valueOf() { return 'foo'; }
        };
    }
};

// should not work but do:
x = {}; // valueOf() returns an object -- a reference to x, itself

x = {
    valueOf() { return 1; } // valueOf() returns a number
};
```

`Object.prototype.valueOf()`, when not overwritten, returns an `object`, not a `string`, so I am confused why those last cases compile, and what I need to change to make them not compile.

I suspect I need to create a generic type that uses the `infer` keyword, but I'm still trying to grok how to use `infer` properly.

Oddly, if I change `valueOf` to `foo`, it does what I expect.

```ts
type Stringable = string | StringableObject;
interface StringableObject {
    foo(): Stringable;
}

// do not compile
x = {};

x = {
    foo() { return 1; }
};

x = {
    foo() {
        return {
            foo() { return 1; }
        };
    }
};
```

I think it must have something to do either with the nature of `valueOf()` itself, or with the fact that `valueOf()` sits on the prototype rather than as a defined on the object itself.  I don't know why this would be the case, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions here so I'll try to address each one individually which I hope will help explain why your code isn't yielding the results you expect.

> `Object.prototype.valueOf()`, when not overwritten, returns an object, not a string, so I am confused why those last cases compile, and what I need to change to make them not compile.

`valueOf()` returns the primitive value of the Object it is called on. String literals (e.g. `'foo'`) are treated as primitives by JavaScript, but since primitives don't have properties, JavaScript coerces primitives into Objects (in fact it will coerce any type as much as possible in order to make an operation valid) in order to allow operations where a primitive would be an invalid type. Take a look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript) for more info on Object coercion. What this means for you is that `valueOf()` may not necessarily return an Object at all, but the primitive value of any type it is called on:

```
> "foo".valueOf()
'foo'
> let x;
> x = {}; x.valueOf()
{}
> x = 10; x.valueOf()
10
```

> I'm overengineering a type that matches a string or an object whose valueOf() when evaluated recursively, eventually returns a string.

The `StringableObject` interface doesn't describe an type whose `valueOf()` method will eventually return a string. It does describe a type whose `valueOf()` method will return a type with a `valueOf()` method that will return a type with a `valueOf()` method and so on ad infinitum and that is exactly what is happening with this line in your first code block:

```
x = {};
```

`x` is being assigned to an Object literal which can be coerced into an `Object` whose `valueOf()` method returns a new primitive that also has a `valueOf()` method that yields a primitive that can be coerced into an `Object` and so on ad infinitum.

In your second code block you change the `valueOf()` method to `foo()`, which does not exist as a method on the global `Object` type and therefore cannot satisfy the infinite `valueOf()` loop that your original `StringableObject` created.

Hope this helps.