# What are the curly braces used for in Plugin<{}>?

Tags: typescript

Reverse engineering https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/hapi-auth-bearer-token/index.d.ts and can’t figure out the following line.

```
declare var BearerToken: Plugin<{}>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Plugin<{}>` means `Plugin` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) with a single type parameter, which is `{}` in this case.

`{}` is the empty object literal type (like `{ someProperty: SomeType }`, but with no properties defined). It isn't the same as `object`, though:

```
const message: {} = 'hello world';
```

compiles (I am not sure why), but

```
const message: object = 'hello world';
```

doesn't.

(I also somehow can't find documentation for this form of types in TypeScript Handbook, but they are used in examples there, e.g. [`let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = o;`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming) or [`type Alias = { num: number }`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases).)

EDIT: `const message: { length: number } = 'hello world';` compiles (which makes sense) and `{ length: number }` is a subtype of `{}`.

Comment: Very strange that `const message: {} = 'hello world';` compile. Sometimes I just can’t figure out TypeScript. Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-in-typescript

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript

Comment: Short story, in JavaScript, apparently a string is a primitive wrapped with an object (coerced) for fraction of time when certain operations are executed on it. By design, you can assign primitives to `{}`, but not to `object`.

Comment: @sunknudsen The first question you linked is more relevant. See the edit as well. I'd like to see TypeScript better documented :(

Comment: Thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018283/in-the-following-example-why-doesn-t-fleet-vehicle3-throw-an-error?

Comment: Feel you Alexey, TypeScript is very quirky. The docs usually are there, somewhere. But the logic takes some getting used to. Love it though.

Comment: Would love to see you expand your answer to include the fact that `{}` is a type assigned to a generic of the `Plugin` type definition. That’s what’s missing from both answers to make them useful to the next person who is trying to figure out these quirks. I might submit an educational answer.

Comment: I thought you understood that part and that's why you only asked about the curly braces :) Edited.

Answer (score 1):

this means BearerToken variable is of type plugin which holds objects inside

`let fruits: Array<string> = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];`

Comment: Thanks Khashayar. So `Plugin<{}>` means `Plugin` is an array of objects? Is `Plugin<{}>` equivalent to `Plugin<object>`? And what’s the difference with `Plugin[object]`?

Comment: not actually Plugin is a type like Number or String you can declare new types in typescript script with `interface` like : 
`interface Plugin { 
   // here is set of property with types which means the object with type Plugin must have these properties like : name: string 
}`

so then ` Plugin<{}>` means our array contains objects of type Plugin

and this is typescript so you see and read more about it in typescript website

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 0):

In general `Plugin` could be a generic class, generic interface or just array which only accepts objects. In the code `Plugin` comes from `Hapi` as per the import statement

```
import {
    Request,
    Plugin,
    ResponseToolkit,
    AuthenticationData,
  } from 'hapi';
```

I did a quick search and found the documentation for [hapi plugins](https://github.com/johnbrett/hapi-auth-bearer-token). I hope this helps