# In the following example, why doesn’t `fleet: vehicle3` throw an error?

Tags: typescript

Trying to figure out [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

My understanding is that `const friday:Transport<Car>` sets `T` to `Car`.

Given `vehicle3` is of type `Bike`, why doesn’t TypeScript throw an error?

```js
'use strict';

interface Vehicle {
  brand: string;
}

interface Bike extends Vehicle {}

interface Car extends Vehicle {}

interface Transport<T> {
  fleet: T;
  manager: string;
}

const vehicle1: Car = {
  brand: 'Honda',
}

const vehicle2: Car = {
  brand: 'Toyota'
}

const vehicle3: Bike = {
  brand: 'Specialized'
}

const today:Transport<Car> = {
  fleet: vehicle1,
  manager: 'Cindy'
};
const tomorrow:Transport<Car[]> = {
  fleet: [vehicle1, vehicle2],
  manager: 'John'
}
const friday:Transport<Car> = {
  fleet: vehicle3,
  manager: 'Steve'
}
```

## Edit

As pointed out by Alexey (thanks!), TypeScript interfaces are [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), therefore the following behaves as I expected because `Car` and `Bike` have conflicting properties.

```
'use strict';

interface Vehicle {
  brand: string;
}

interface Bike extends Vehicle {
  rider: string
}

interface Car extends Vehicle {
  driver: string
}

interface Transport<T> {
  fleet: T;
  manager: string;
}

const vehicle1: Car = {
  brand: 'Honda',
  driver: 'Alex'
}

const vehicle2: Car = {
  brand: 'Toyota',
  driver: 'Bob'
}

const vehicle3: Bike = {
  brand: 'Specialized',
  rider: 'George'
}

const today:Transport<Car> = {
  fleet: vehicle1,
  manager: 'Cindy'
};
const tomorrow:Transport<Car[]> = {
  fleet: [vehicle1, vehicle2],
  manager: 'John'
}
const friday:Transport<Car> = {
  fleet: vehicle3,
  manager: 'Steve'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified to

```
const v4: Car = vehicle3
```

TypeScript interfaces are structural, so `Vehicle`, `Car`, and `Bike` are all the same. See [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

Comment: Thanks so much Alexey!

Comment: You may also want to check discriminated unions (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)