# If to call any Array.prototype function upon a string, does the string get converted to an object? Is it a runtime-friendly operation? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, call, prototypejs

To clarify the situation, I conducted a simple test, and below is a runnable code snippet:

```js
function test() {
    const str = 'abcdef';
    alert(Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, (result, _, i, _str) => {
        if(!i) result.push(`typeof str: ${typeof str}`);
        else if(i === 1) result.push(`typeof _str: ${typeof _str}`);
        else if(i === 2) result.push(`_str == str: ${_str == str}`);
        else if(i === 3) result.push(`_str === str: ${_str === str}`);
        else if(i === 4) result.push(`str: "${str}", _str: "${_str}"`);
        else result.push(`_str instanceof String: ${_str instanceof String}`);
        return result;
    }, []).join('\n'));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click me to run the test!</button>
```

The test showed the result I didn't expected: `_str` is an object and `str` is a string primitive, they are not equal if checked with `===` – however, if to join them to another string, both result in "abcd". I often call `Array.prorotype` functions (mostly – forEach) upon strings and till recently was sure that it is a much better option in terms of performance, than e.g. `[...str].forEach` or `[...str].reduce`, because calling does not convert a string to an array, but, as turned out to be, the string is converted under the hood to some object! Am I missing something?

UPD: this mysterious _str object is an instance of String.

Comment: It has to do with calling `Array.prototype.reduce` in the context of a String. Under the hood everything inherits from Object. You'll notice that `typeof ['a', 'b', 'c'] === 'object'`, even though `['a', 'b', 'c'] instanceof Array`. I doubt what you are doing would be a performance gain. It looks like a bad practice to me.

Comment: I assume that it has to do with **coercion** between string primitive and String object; however if to call `Array.prototype` functions upon a string the coersion is not implicit, but explicit. It is impossible to access any string key or e.g. length property without converting it to an object. I read a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript 
So, I don't think that it will affect performance, because in any case all manipulations with string keys are done with implicit converting a primitive to an object.