# When does string become an iterable object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, for-of-loop

I read [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/iterable#string-is-iterable). And I can't get something. The text is saying that strings are iterable. And [here](https://javascript.info/iterable#array-like) I can read that iterables are objects that implement the `Symbol.iterator` method.

So, when and how string becomes an iterable object? Does it mean that `for..of` turns primitive string into the “object wrapper”? Am I right?

Comment: It always is right. That method is here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675127/is-string-a-primitive-type-or-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the String class does have a [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) method, and you can use `for..of` on a string to produce the results as in this example:

```js
var myString = "So, when and how string becomes an iterable object?";
for (let char of myString) {
  console.log(char);
}
```